# Not firing after update trigger when updating from insert trigger

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have two triggers on one table, one fires on insert and updates the row with additional info from other tables

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[eTteamTg]
ON  [dbo].[entryTable]  
AFTER INSERT 
AS  
BEGIN 
    UPDATE entryTable
    SET shiftTeam = (SELECT TOP 1 shiftTeamMemb.teamId 
                     FROM shiftTeamMemb 
                     WHERE shiftTeamMemb.personalNumber = i.personalNumber)
    FROM entryTable
    INNER JOIN inserted i ON i.ID = entryTable.ID
END
```

And second one fires after update

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[eThistoryUpdTg] ON  [dbo].[entryTable]  
AFTER update
AS  
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO eThistory(my columns)
        SELECT
            *, HOST_Name() + ' ' + SUSER_NAME() + ' Upd', GETDATE() 
        FROM
            deleted
END
```

What I need to do is to **not fire** `AFTER UPDATE` trigger when I am updating the rows with `AFTER INSERT` trigger. Is it possible ?

Comment: Your `insert` trigger appears to be broken. The subquery is uncorrelated (It introduces a separate reference to `inserted` rather than what I'm guessing you were trying to do, reference `i`) and so multi-row inserts will generate an error along the lines of "subquery returned more than one value".

Comment: Oh I see now, updated the question @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. It won't return that error. Instead it'll silently corrupt your data because you've forced it to with the `top 1`. Again, that subquery is *uncorrelated*. So if `inserted` contains *multiple* rows with *different* `personalNumber` values, *one* of those values will successfully cause a lookup to occur in `shiftTeamMemb` and then *every* row originally inserted will receive that value.

Comment: Using `TOP 1` *without* an explicit `ORDER BY` is pointless - which row are you expecting to get? Since without an `ORDER BY`, there's no guarantee of any ordering - you're basically getting an **arbitrary** row .... is that really what you're looking for??

Comment: I agree with you that this subquery is not well written,  I will rewrite it later, for now I need to solve my main problem in this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to merge this two triggers into one:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[eTteamTg]
ON  [dbo].[entryTable]  
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS  
BEGIN 
    UPDATE entryTable
    SET shiftTeam = (SELECT TOP 1 shiftTeamMemb.teamId 
                     FROM shiftTeamMemb 
                     WHERE shiftTeamMemb.personalNumber = i.personalNumber)
    FROM entryTable
    INNER JOIN inserted i ON i.ID = entryTable.ID

    INSERT INTO eThistory(my columns)
    SELECT
        *, HOST_Name() + ' ' + SUSER_NAME() + ' Upd', GETDATE() 
    FROM
        deleted
END
```

Then after INSERT, it will update `shiftTeam` and `deleted1 will not be used.

After UPDATE, it will update `shiftTeam` and use `deleted` to get previous (even to above update) values.

Or if you don't need to update `shiftTeam` in case of UPDATE on this table you can add IF statement:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[eTteamTg]
ON  [dbo].[entryTable]  
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS  
BEGIN 

    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM deleted) = 0 --That means it was INSERT
    BEGIN
        UPDATE entryTable
        SET shiftTeam = (SELECT TOP 1 shiftTeamMemb.teamId 
                         FROM shiftTeamMemb 
                         WHERE shiftTeamMemb.personalNumber = i.personalNumber)
        FROM entryTable
        INNER JOIN inserted i ON i.ID = entryTable.ID
    END

    INSERT INTO eThistory(my columns)
    SELECT
        *, HOST_Name() + ' ' + SUSER_NAME() + ' Upd', GETDATE() 
    FROM
        deleted
END
```

Comment: Great! This was exactly what I needed, I did not know that you can do same trigger on more actions. This way is pretty clever. I have to use the second way, because I need to update it only on insert

Answer (score 1):

Implement your second trigger like this,

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[eThistoryUpdTg] ON [dbo].[entryTable]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO eThistory (my columns)
    SELECT *
        ,HOST_Name() + ' ' + SUSER_NAME() + ' Upd'
        ,GETDATE()
    FROM deleted d
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT TOP 1 shiftTeamMemb.teamId
            FROM shiftTeamMemb
            INNER JOIN inserted I ON i.personalNumber = shiftTeamMemb.personalNumber
            INNER JOIN entryTable E ON E.ID = I.ID
            WHERE shiftTeamMemb.personalNumber = i.personalNumber
            )
END
```